# Как с помощью python сделать СДНФ (Совершенная дизъюнктивная нормальная форма)? Что должно получиться на фото ниже

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
print("x1, x2, x3, F(x1,x2,x3)")
a = np.array([[0,0,0,1],
               [0,0,1,1],
               [0,1,0,0],
               [0,1,1,0],
               [1,0,0,1],
               [1,0,1,1],
               [1,1,0,0],
               [1,1,1,1]])
print(a)
print(" ")
print("Воспользуемся правилом построения СДНФ:")
print("x1, x2, x3, F(x1,x2,x3)")
res = a[a[:, 3] == 1]
print(res)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что вы ожидаете получить в качестве результата (в терминах Python)?

Comment: То, что на фото. Хотя бы приблизительно похожое. Или в каком либо виде построить СДНФ.

Comment: На фото формула из дискретной математики. Как вы представляете ее себе в терминах Python?

Comment: Если честно, я вообще думал, что можно как-то написать на питоне эту формулу. Но похоже, что нельзя. Так что, я даже не представляю.

Comment: С какой целью вы это делаете? Может быть поняв вашу цель, легче будет подсказать решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
```

исходная таблица истинности в виде Pandas DataFrame:

```
In [112]: df = pd.DataFrame(
     ...:  [[0,0,0,1],
     ...:   [0,0,1,1],
     ...:   [0,1,0,0],
     ...:   [0,1,1,0],
     ...:   [1,0,0,1],
     ...:   [1,0,1,1],
     ...:   [1,1,0,0],
     ...:   [1,1,1,1]],
     ...:   columns = ["x1", "x2", "x3", "F(x1,x2,x3)"]
     ...: )

In [113]: df
Out[113]:
   x1  x2  x3  F(x1,x2,x3)
0   0   0   0            1
1   0   0   1            1
2   0   1   0            0
3   0   1   1            0
4   1   0   0            1
5   1   0   1            1
6   1   1   0            0
7   1   1   1            1
```

---

Решение:

сначала получим инвертированную таблицу истинности где результат равен `1`:

```
In [114]: r = (~df.loc[df['F(x1,x2,x3)']==1, ['x1','x2','x3']].astype(bool)).astype('int8')

In [115]: r
Out[115]:
   x1  x2  x3
0   1   1   1
1   1   1   0
4   0   1   1
5   0   1   0
7   0   0   0
```

теперь на ее основе можно получить СДНФ:

```
In [116]: res = (r.apply(lambda r: '({}{} ^ {}{} ^ {}{})'.format('!'*r['x1'], 'x1',
     ...:                                                        '!'*r['x2'], 'x2',
     ...:                                                        '!'*r['x3'], 'x3'),
     ...:                                                        axis=1)
     ...:         .str.cat(sep = ' v '))
     ...:

In [117]: print(res)
(!x1 ^ !x2 ^ !x3) v (!x1 ^ !x2 ^ x3) v (x1 ^ !x2 ^ !x3) v (x1 ^ !x2 ^ x3) v (x1 ^ x2 ^ x3)
```

**UPDATE:** вспомогательная инвертированная матрица нужна для удобства.

Правило: *Если значение переменной равно 0, то она записывается с инверсией. Если значение переменной равно 1, то без инверсии.*

В ответе используется следующий трюк:

```
In [29]: '!' * 0 + 'x1'
Out[29]: 'x1'

In [30]: '!' * 1 + 'x1'
Out[30]: '!x1'
```

т.е. чтобы поставить отрицание (восклицательный знак) надо чтобы соответствующее значение в матрице равнялось единице, а по правилу построения СДНФ, отрицание ставиться в случае если элемент равен нулю. Поэтому удобнее воспользоваться инвертированной таблицей, чтобы использовать трюк, орисанный выше.

Comment: А почему, когда мы получили инвертированную таблицу, данные рядков отличаются от изначальной таблицы? И почему СДНФ не совпадает по таблице?

Comment: @AshleyKing, инвертированная и должна отличаться -  это как плёнка негатив (там где в исходной матрице стояли единицы будут нули и наоборот). СДНФ, по-моему, соответствует исходной матрице и совпадает с вашим вариантом...

Comment: Да, СДНФ совпадает, я что-то просмотрел. А можно как-то сделать так, что значения таблицы СДНФ были такие же, как и в исходной? И еще такой вопрос, как можно составить СКНФ (это тоже, что и СДНФ, только с 0, а не с 1)? А то у меня ответ СКНФ получается с точностью наоборот.

Comment: @AshleyKing, инвертированная таблица - это __вспомогательная__ таблица, просто так проще сформировать СДНФ. ЕЕ показывать не обязательно. Сейчас отвечу вам в вашем новом SO вопросе про СКНФ...

Comment: @AshleyKing, добавил пояснение - для чего нужна вспомогательная таблица

Answer (score 3):

Можете воспользоваться библиотекой [pyeda](https://pyeda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```
from pyeda.inter import *
import numpy as np
x = exprvars('x', 3)
a = np.array([[0,0,0,1],
               [0,0,1,1],
               [0,1,0,0],
               [0,1,1,0],
               [1,0,0,1],
               [1,0,1,1],
               [1,1,0,0],
               [1,1,1,1]])
vector = [i[3] for i in a]
f = truthtable(x, vector)
print(f)
print(truthtable2expr(f))
```

Вывод:

```
x[2] x[1] x[0]
   0    0    0 : 1
   0    0    1 : 1
   0    1    0 : 0
   0    1    1 : 0
   1    0    0 : 1
   1    0    1 : 1
   1    1    0 : 0
   1    1    1 : 1

Or(And(~x[0], ~x[1], ~x[2]), And(x[0], ~x[1], ~x[2]), And(~x[0], ~x[1], x[2]), And(x[0], ~x[1], x[2]), And(x[0], x[1], x[2]))
```